# Using AvatarAPI with ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, avatar

I have a use case where I need to use Avatar API(https://avatarapi.com/) that fetches user profile based on the email address. I tried adding a script to useEffect hook to render the data but it does not show anything.

I am using the Javascript API from https://avatarapi.com/

Following is the link of my implementation: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-yxfcpw

I have tried to implement it using fetch and extracting the image url using Regex and rendering the image accordingly.
My implementation mentioned above worked but now it complains  `You can only call this free script 100 times, perhaps you should see our API on www.avatarapi.com?`

Any help would be appreciated.

Note: I cannot use the XML API.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `XML API` method of AvatarApi website

Comment: I am using the Javascript API and I cannot switch to XML api